# ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator'

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator

I want to run a segmentation code (with this link in github: https://github.com/taigw/brats17) on Google Colab and I'm faced with this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.data import Iterator
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
Iterator = tf.data.Iterator
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a version conflict for tensorflow. The `data` package has been upgraded from `tf.contrib.data` to a core package `tf.data`. You are probably using a newer version of tensorflow than that code was developed for. You can install an older version of tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow==1.5` (that would install version 1.5 for example).